# Ubuntu as router with squid

Tags: ubuntu, router, squid

What i bassically want to do is use an ubuntu machine to act as my router but with squid to block some addresses. But i don't want to change user network settings.

Explanation:

Current configuration

pc1, pc2, pc3 ... <-----> Switch <-----> Router

All my network pc's have an ip in this range

10.217.75.2 - 10.217.75.254

SM:255.255.255.0

GW:10.217.75.1

My router (which i cannot modify it's a public sector router) gives this range and this GW

What i want to do is use an ubuntu machine or something else just before the router to act like it was the router itself in order not to change anything to user network settings. I also need something like squid to block access to certain pages. So I imagine a network like this:

pc1, pc2, pc3 ... <-----> Switch <-----> Ubuntu with squid <----> Current Router

the thing is that i have many users and i cannot change their network settings (locked with passwords), is there a way to make this "Ubuntu machine" work as if it was the router and just filter traffic before forwarding it to the current real router??? All other solutions i've tried either use another subnet for forwarding either changing proxy settings on every broswer...but i cannot use any of these solutions. Do you have any link or solution that i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, your requirements are too strict. Indeed, the setup you would need to do would look like you thought it would:

```
pc1, pc2, pc3 ... <-----> Switch <-----> Ubuntu with squid <----> Current Router
```

However, your local computers (the network clients) will NOT go through your Ubuntu box unless you specifically tell them to. You will **need** to modify your Gateway. Change it to the IP address of your Ubuntu box.

If you cannot change the Gateway, then all the clients will continue to connect through that public router and there is no way to tell them to do that otherwise.

Sorry, I know it's not what you wanted to hear, but this is how networking is supposed to work. Otherwise, if what you wanted worked, one could use that maliciously to highjack people's connections, or man-in-the-middle attack them, in a public place like a Coffee shop or library. I personally think it's best that this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you didn't dissapointed me at all, I had all these in my mind, but i thought that i might be missing something that could actually work. I wondered if i could make my Ubuntu machine work that way!